How to parse JSONB text into the []string slice
I have a problem with correct parsing of JSONB to []string in golang
query := sq.StatementBuilder.
    PlaceholderFormat(sq.Dollar).
    Select(
        ...
    "logbooks.stages -> logbook_entries.next_stage_id ->> 'employee_position_ids' as employee_position_ids."
    ).
    From("logbook_entries").
    Join("logbooks on logbooks.id = logbook_entries.logbook_id and logbooks.current_version=logbook_entries.logbook_version").
        ...

Later i tried to parse the row into my custom struct
type incompleteEntry struct {
    ...
    EmployeePositionIDs []string
}

for rows.Next() {
    var item incompleteEntry
    err := rows.Scan(
        ...
        &item.EmployeePositionIDs,
    )
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
}

In result I got the following error message
 can't scan into dest[6]: cannot scan text (OID 25) in text format into *[]string

In project I use jackc/pgxpool and as a query builder squirrel package

You have to scan into []byte or json.RawMessage, then unmarshal separately.

@Peter Yep, works Thank you.

@Peter Fancy leaving that as a real answer?
